# How to get count from nested array in react

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to fetch like counts from the nested array(Likes) within the posts object array.

I'm trying to do

```
  <Like like={id} likes={Likes.data.count} />
```

but getting this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
```

[image]

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {UpdatePost, getLikeCount, postLike} from '../actions/';
import Like from './Like';
import Axios from '../Axios';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    button:{
        marginRight:'30px'
    }
}
class PostItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
            myId: 0,
            likes:0
        }
    }
    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }
    }

    getLikes = (id) =>  {
        // console.log(id);
        this.props.getLikeCount(id)
        const myLike = this.props.likeCount
        const like = this.props.likeCount
    }
    render(){
        const {title, id, userId, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate, Likes, clickLike} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                {/* {this.getLikes(id)} */}
                   <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                   {/* if else teneray operator */}
                   {isEditing ? (
                          <Editable editField={myTitle ? myTitle : title} editChange={editChange}/>
                   ): (
                       <div>
                           {title}
                       </div>    
                   )}         
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography component="p">
                       {post_content}
                       <h5>
                           by: {username}</h5>
                       <Typography color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                       <Like like={id} likes={Likes.data.count} />
                   </Typography>
                   {!isEditing ? (
                       <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                           Edit
                       </Button>
                   ):(     
                       // pass id, and myTitle which as we remember myTitle is the new value when updating the title
                        <div>
                            <Button 
                                disabled={myTitle.length <= 3}
                                variant="outlined" 
                                onClick={this.onUpdate(id, myTitle)}>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                variant="outlined" 
                                style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                                onClick={editForm(null)}>
                                Close
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                   )}
                   {!isEditing && (
                    <Button
                        style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                    )}
           </div>
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    likeCount:state.post.likes
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    getLikeCount: (id) => dispatch(getLikeCount(id)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id))
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

**PostList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DeletePost,  getLikeCount, postLike, UpdatePost,EditChange, DisableButton} from '../actions/';
import PostItem from './PostItem';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    }
}
class PostList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            title: '',
        }
    }
    // Return a new function. Otherwise the DeletePost action will be dispatch each
     // time the Component rerenders.
    removePost = (id) => () => {
        this.props.DeletePost(id);
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            title: e.target.value
        })
    }
    formEditing = (id) => ()=> {;
        this.props.EditChange(id);
    }
    getLikes = (id) =>  {
        // console.log(id);
        this.props.getLikeCount(id)
        console.log(this.props.likeCount)
    }
    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>

                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem

                             myTitle={this.state.title} 
                             editChange={this.onChange} 
                             editForm={this.formEditing} 
                             isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                             removePost={this.removePost} 
                             {...post} 
                        />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    EditChange: (id) => dispatch(EditChange(id)),
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    getLikeCount: (id) => dispatch(getLikeCount(id)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),
    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
    DeletePost: (id) => dispatch(DeletePost(id))
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**backend**

```
router.get('/myPosts',  async  (req, res) =>{
   await models.Post.findAll({ 
        include:[{
            model:models.Likes
        }],    
        order:[ 
        ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
        ], limit: 6 })
       .then( (posts) =>{
           res.json(posts);

       })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Likes` is an `Array` so you can get the length by doing `Likes.length`. Or if you want the total of `true` like, you can do `Likes.reduce((count, ({ like })) => like ? count + 1 : count), 0)`

Comment: `Likes.length` will do, my next challenge is being able to update the number of likes without re-rendering on like onClick aciton. Im using redux, and i think their is a way to do this. ill figure this out. Thanks Lucas